# How to call request with API key in Python

Tags: python, json, request, key

I have API like this:

[image: api]

I want to call this API in Python, this is my code :

```
def get_province():
headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': api_key
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

return response.json()
```

But, I've got

> error 500 : Internal Server Error.

I think there's something wrong with the header. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging from screenshot, it should be `Authorization` not `x-api-key` i.e.

```
headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': api_key
    }
```

Please test that and write what is result

Comment: its working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an API key like this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

# other code you wrote
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('apikey', 'ILove99Dollars')

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need the full stack trace to find the error source. Also the api_key has to be passed to the function called (get_province()).

```py
import requests

headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'x-api-key': 'yourapikey'}
search_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers )
```